# Linking with boost .lib

Tags: c++, boost

I'm getting a link time error `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc80-mt-gd-1_44.lib'` I recently downloaded boost which came with `boost_serialization-vc80-mt-gd-1_44.lib` but the compiler seems to be looking for one starting with `libboost` so i renamed it. but then it fails to find `.dll` at runtime. I tried to rename the dll but doesn't seem this helps.

While loading dll: `An unhandled non-continuable STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND exception was thrown during process load`

Comment: Are you using visual studio? Have you checked your project settings to see where the linker looks for libraries, and what libs your project is attempting to link to?

Comment: Yes. I've added the boost library folder, it links to .lib after i renamed but fails to find .dll in same folder as lib

Answer (score 3):

There are many different versions of each boost library: multi-threaded, single-threaded, static, dynamic, etc. The ones starting with "lib" are the static libraries, the ones without "lib" are the lib files used to link to the DLL versions. You can see this by looking at the lib file size.

If you are auto-linking boost, it means that the linker is looking for the static version of serialization. If you don't have such a file, it means you didn't build it. Another alternative is to use the installer available at http://www.boostpro.com. It allows you to select which boost libraries (static, dynamic, ST, MT, VS Version, etc) to download and install.

The other option is to disable auto-linking: see this post on the boost mailing list: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/12/15697.php